# Creating a Table in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, format, tabular

Let me preface my question by saying that I am completely unqualified to be working in Fortran 77, but alas, here I am and I'm learning what I can.

I'm working on a project involving modeling flame properties under different conditions.
Here I have a snippet that is outputting the first row in a table, giving labels for the rows underneath their appropriate columns. (KSYM is a array of strings that label the different chemical compounds present)

```
   WRITE(LOUT,1) "Standoff(cm)", "Density(g/cm3)", 
 +  "HeatReleaseRate(erg/cm3/s)","Temperature(K)",
 +  KSYM(1),KSYM(2),KSYM(3),KSYM(4),KSYM(5),KSYM(6),KSYM(7),
 +  KSYM(8),KSYM(9),KSYM(10),KSYM(11),KSYM(12),KSYM(13),KSYM(14),
 +  KSYM(15),KSYM(16),KSYM(17),KSYM(18),KSYM(19),KSYM(20),
 +  KSYM(21),KSYM(22),KSYM(23),KSYM(24),KSYM(25),KSYM(26),
 +  KSYM(27),KSYM(28),KSYM(29),KSYM(30),KSYM(31),KSYM(32),
 +  KSYM(33)
```

then later in a loop for each standoff interval

```
    WRITE(LOUT,6) X(J),F(J),HR(J),(SN(N,J), N=1,NATJ-1)
```

And here's the formats:

```
 1     FORMAT(A16,3X,A16,3X,A30,3X,A16,3X,80(A16,3X))
 2     FORMAT(I10)
 3     FORMAT(3(I10,3X))
 4     FORMAT(3(E17.7,3X))
 5     FORMAT(80(E17.7,3X))
 6     FORMAT(F17.7,3X,F17.7,3X,F20.7,3X,80(E15.5,3X))
```

My problem is that the data comes out in away that the labels in the first row and their appropriate columns don't stay aligned after the first few columns, making it difficult to read and manipulate.

The two possible solutions I can think of:
1. would be to either use the "T" format descriptor to make absolute columns
2. ignore the issue of immediate readability, insert commas or semicommas after every entry to then open in excel as a .CSV file

Since I'm going to end up graphing the data eventually, I might as well do option 2.
I've tried just adding "," in between each entry in the first code snippet, but I kept getting syntax errors, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT:

To test idea 2, I've added ",", inbetween each entry.

```
       WRITE(LOUT,*) 'Name',KSYM(1),';',KSYM(2),';',KSYM(3),';',
 +  KSYM(4),';',KSYM(5),';',KSYM(6),';',KSYM(7),';',KSYM(8),';',
 +  KSYM(9),';',KSYM(10),';',KSYM(11),';',KSYM(12),';',
 +  KSYM(13),';',KSYM(14),';',KSYM(15),';',KSYM(16),';',
 +  KSYM(17),';',KSYM(18),';',KSYM(19),';',KSYM(20),';',
 +  KSYM(21),';',KSYM(22),';',KSYM(23),';',KSYM(24),';',
 +  KSYM(25),';',KSYM(26),';',KSYM(27),';',KSYM(28),';',
 +  KSYM(29),';',KSYM(30),';',KSYM(31),';',KSYM(32),';',
 +  KSYM(33)
```

But same syntax errors as before. I am using a peculiar compiler pgf77 if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you are using the fixed-form source, try adding the -Mextend switch (this will allow the line length up to 128 symbols). If your lines are longer than the fixed-form limit, this may be the cause of weird syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that your field widths in formats 1 and 6 are different.  In format 1 you have spacings of 3X and strings (labels) of length 16.    Except one is A30.  In format 6, used for the values, you have spaces of 3, and fields for the numeric item with different lengths such as 17, 20 or 15.   If you make every numeric format item 16 long, except for the 3rd item, then things should line up.

The first write would be much easier to read by replacing 33 separately indexed values of the array with an implied do-loop: (ksym (i), i=1,33).   Might as well use array features instead of writing all of that stuff out!

Answer (score 0):

Format statements are largely incompatible with variable width output such as CSV.  Instead, just use list-directed output:

```
    write (LOUT,*) 'Standoff(cm), Density(g/cm3), HeatReleaseRate(erg/cm3/s), Temperature(K)'

    do 101 i=1,n
    write (LOUT,*) X(J), ',', F(J), ',', HR(J), ',', (SN(N,J), ',', N=1,NATJ-1)
101 continue
```

(untested)

Comment: What is the difference between ' and " ?

Comment: Probably none.  Traditionally, FORTRAN was written with ' to delimit strings.

Comment: Updated my question with my progress.

Comment: Actually, I think the F77 standard mandated the single-quote. But it was all so long ago and far away.....

Comment: The code as I found it uses double-quotes to surround inline strings as from my first code snippet and it worked fine.

Comment: According to the syntax diagrams in my copy of "Programming in Standard FORTRAN 77" by Balfour & Marwick (strongly recommended if you can get hod of  a copy), which are taken from the ANSI 77 Standard, only single quotes are allowed. But I'm sure all modern FORTRAN compilers allow both.

Comment: As of Fortran 90, you can use either.